# Soundcloud link embed

Tags: php, soundcloud

I am a High School student, and in my Web Design course, we are having a genius hour project. Also known as 20% time, we take an hour every Friday in order to create our own website. For mine, I'm making a website called  [stressreliefsounds](http://www.stressrelief.co.nf)  . Now, as you can see, I have the soundcloud player with one set programmed in. However, what I wish to do is to create a text field on the home page where a user can place their own set, then choose their own background from a list. I am a fairly new programmer, and so far, everything I've tried has been a bust. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An input element inside a form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search Sounds..." />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search!" />
</form>
```

Then you'll have to use the SoundCloud Search API found here: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs#search

What it looks like you have to do, is register a SoundCloud App with your account, and that'll allow people to search SoundCloud on your behalf. Then your form on your site will have to send the data to SoundCloud through this API and you output the search results to your site for people to choose from.

For a Novice programmer, you're diggin into some major stuff. Kudos, hope this helps!

Comment: Oh boy, this sounds incredibly complicated. Oh well, you have to start somewhere! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: No problem. For a "Genius Hour Project" this would totally win it I think. I was the top student in my web design classes as well because I had already taught myself a lot. (Probably more than the teacher since he was asking ME questions!) Good luck!